# JMapper XML Map to a single value

Tags: java, xml

I'm looking how to handle a Map<String,String> map; to get a key value from it. For example in dozer :

```
<a map-get-method="get" key="valueFromTheMap">map</a>
```

Thank you

ManyToOne? https://github.com/jmapper-framework/jmapper-core/wiki/Many-To-One

Comment: Sounds like you are asking how to get a value from a key/value store. Just run 
`String value = map.get(key);`
I do not believe that was your question, so where does JMapper get into the game?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how in JMapper in XML get from a Map<String,String> fields for example the value from key field1. 
I have a Map from one side (Source) and I want to get only one element from this map for my (Destination). Thanks

Comment: Maybe with conversion https://github.com/jmapper-framework/jmapper-core/wiki/Explicit-Conversions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717110/configurable-e-g-xml-java-bean-to-bean-mapping-framework

interesting

Comment: https://github.com/jmapper-framework/jmapper-core/wiki/Conversion-examples